# What's the difference in meaning and usage between 'to get a present off someone' and 'to get a present from someone'?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

What's the difference in meaning and usage between

to get a present from someone

and

to get a present off someone

Answer (score 5):

To my ear *off* in that sense is non-standard. The OED says of this sense " Now chiefly *colloquial*".

It is certainly common in some British colloquial varieties (I'm not sure about outside Britain), but I would not say it.

As far as I can tell it means exactly the same as *from*.

Comment: As an American English speaker, I was not familiar with the colloquialism. "I got a present off someone" could also mean that I sought and took a present from someone (maybe that person didn't intend to give it to me). Like how Gollum got his "birthday present".

Comment: I seem to remember a time when it was used more often than it is today - as regards a present.  But people still speak of acquiring (buying) things "off the internet", "off a stall in the market place",  "off a friend", or "off the back of a lorry" (euphemism for stealing).

Comment: Where I grew up, you could ask someone "Who did you get it off of?"  meaning, "Who gave you that?" or "How did you come by that?" But it wouldn't be used of a birthday present, but of something the speaker assumes was given ad hoc under some unusual circumstances, perhaps in a swap, or because you won it in a bet.

Comment: @WS2 - if you got something off the back of a lorry, it was very often sold to you cheaply by someone who had themselves stolen it or received it from e.g. a gang.

Comment: _I once saw, in Tesco, him off Corrie, you know, the one who plays Roy Cropper._ This actually happened.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, strictly it is a euphemism for stolen goods.  They have usually "fallen off the back of a lorry".

Comment: @WS2 - a fairly common con trick in London used to be street salesmen offering apparently stolen 'expensive' perfume from a suitcase - appealing to the British liking for a dodgy bargain. People would gather around, some being stooges, and money would change hands briskly, until another stooge would call 'Police!' and everyone would vanish. The bottles weren't stolen; they were fake.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I've heard of traders in places like Petticoat Lane Market who virtually advertise their merchandise as stolen. An Australian I knew years ago, when I lived there, enjoyed telling his mates about a bloke in London who said to him "You don't ask me where I get these leather jackets from and I won't ask you where you get your money from". They weren't stolen - nor were they made of leather.

Comment: @WS2 - ah, cheap leather jackets! What about the ones from Morocco that are real leather, and which please the wearer until the first time they are caught in the rain. The cheap black dye runs out into the clothes underneath, and the wearer is surrounded by a strong smell of the human urine used to crudely and poorly 'tan' the leather.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Perhaps we should ease up on this before the administrators think we are here to promote Marks & Spencers.